# Ionic, Angular - How to properly use a counted row on a TypeScript condition? Throws cannot be applied to types

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following function that will return the count of plants based on a given query identifier.

```
    countPlantByCropIdentifier(crop_identifier) {
    let values = [
      crop_identifier
    ];

    var query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM plants WHERE crop_identifier = ?;"
    return this.storage.executeSql(query, values).then(data => {
      var parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.rows.item(0)));
      return parsed.count;
    });
  }
```

While I can get the `parsed.count` result. I cannot access it as a condition when I use it on another method on ionic/angular.

This is where I am trying to figure it out.

```
    processPlantSync(data) {
    var plantExist = this.countPlantByCropIdentifier(data.crop_identifier);

    if (plantExist > 1) { // <-- Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Promise<any>' and 'number'.ts(2365)

    }
  }
```

[image]

It throws the following error, how can I properly parse this and use as a condition?

Comment: `countPlantByCropIdentifier` returns a `Promise`, so `var plantExist = await this.countPlantByCropIdentifier(data.crop_identifier)` or `this.countPlantByCropIdentifier(data.crop_identifier).then(plantExist => ...)`

Comment: that simple? works ! thanks